# Trying to delete Identity Framework roles using Ajax

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

Hi guys hope you are all fine.
I am facing a issue or rather say bug, i am developing a application in .net core mvc. I am using identity scaffolding for my project. I am creating roles, updating it all are working fine but whenever i trying to delete any specific role it doesn't delete the role.

Controller code for deleting role:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
        {
            var objFromDb = _db.Roles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
            if (objFromDb == null) 
            {
                TempData[SD.Error] = "Role not found.";
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Roles));
            }

            var userRolesForThisRole = _db.UserRoles.Where(u => u.RoleId == id).Count();
            if(userRolesForThisRole > 0)
            {
                TempData[SD.Error] = "Cannot delete this role, since there are users assigned to this         role.";
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Roles));
            }
            await _roleManager.DeleteAsync(objFromDb);
            TempData[SD.Success] = "Role deleted successfully.";
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Roles));
        }
```

Note: I am using ajax for showing roles and dynamically add buttons:

```
{
  "data": "id", "render": function (data) {
   return `
          <form asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="${data}" method="post">
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" onclick="return confirm('Are you   sure you want to delete this?')">
            <i class="fas fa-trash mr-1"></i>
                    DELETE
            </button>
          </form> 
                                    `
    }
}
```

I am trying to delete role using this but it doesn't delete role. Please help me!

Comment: What message are you seeing after you click the delete button?

Comment: In your form, can you specify asp-controller?

Comment: After clicking on delete button nothing happend the page refreshes and nothing else.

Comment: I tried i used asp controller but nothing happend too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you'd like to generate `<form>` for each identity role in function `render` on client side.

> `<form asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="${data}" method="post">`

Please note that your above dynamic form tag as below will be appended to html Dom directly, it will not generate expected HTML form with correct `action` attribute based on route data, which cause form submission not work well.

To make form submission works well, you can try to modify your code like below.

step1: you applied `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` on your action method, please refer to following code to generate and store an Antiforgery token in web page

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Antiforgery
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    var requestToken = Antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
}

<input id="RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="@requestToken" />

@*your html code *@
```

step2: dynamically generate html form and include a hidden filed with Request VerificationToken

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        var url = "/Home/Delete";
        var xsrfToken = $("#RequestVerificationToken").val();
      
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            //...
            //other options 
            //...
            "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `
                        <form action="${url}/${data}" method="post">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-small" onclick="return confirm('Are you   sure you want to delete this?')">
                            <i class="fas fa-trash mr-1"></i>
                            DELETE
                            </button>
                                            <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="${xsrfToken}">
                        </form> 
                                `
                }
            }
            ]
        } );
    })
</script>
```

*Test Result*

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much brother it works well. Can i ask why do you used antiforgerytoken? I'm new to identity as i am learning this so can you please explain me? Second what if i want to add sweet alerts before deleting just like i am using return confirm function but i want to use sweet alert before deleting it asks for are you sure you want to delete after clicking yes it deletes.

Comment: `Can i ask why do you used antiforgerytoken?` I just checked your code and found that you applied ***ValidateAntiForgeryToken*** attribute on your backend action, which will cause 400 error if your client request do not include valid VerificationToken, so I suggested to generate and include VerificationToken on client side. For more information about Antiforgery in ASP.NET Core, please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: To integrate and use sweet alert, you need to add required JS and CSS files in your app, then initiate and trigger sweet alert on `DELETE` button client side click event.

Comment: `Thankyou so much brother it works well` Hi @MohamadUsman, you can accept it as answer to help others quickly find this case and answer to fix similar issue.